# SQL query count occurrences then group by day but also fill missing days

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table called `diseaseScores` which has calculation results. Each hour a running score is calculated (`currentScore`). The objective of this query is to group the hourly scores by the day (`obsDate`), then count the `numberOfhours` where the running score is at a level considered high. High is greater than 16 (`currentScore > 16`).

My query so far is:

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, obsDate)) AS obsDate, 
    (CASE 
        WHEN count(id) > 12 THEN count(id) 
        ELSE 0 
     END) numOfHoursAtHigh 
FROM
    diseaseScores
WHERE 
    diseaseID = 2 
    AND siteID = 72160 
    AND numOfRotationYears = 3 
    AND currentScore > 16 
    AND month(obsDate) IN (6) 
GROUP BY
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, obsDate)) 
ORDER BY
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, obsDate));
```

The query returns results for 13 days of the month. I wish to fill the gaps so I a have a record for each of the day of the month. The gaps need to have a `numOfHoursAtHigh` result of 0.

How can I do this? This is for SQL Server 2008 +

The result set being returned is:

```
        2016-06-04 00:00:00.000     0
        2016-06-05 00:00:00.000     23
        2016-06-06 00:00:00.000     23
        2016-06-07 00:00:00.000     23
        2016-06-08 00:00:00.000     3
        2016-06-09 00:00:00.000     23
        2016-06-10 00:00:00.000     0
        2016-06-17 00:00:00.000     13
        2016-06-18 00:00:00.000     23
        2016-06-19 00:00:00.000     0
        2016-06-20 00:00:00.000     14
        2016-06-21 00:00:00.000     23
        2016-06-22 00:00:00.000     16
```

UPDATE : So using a modified version of knobcreekmans approach (was doubling up certain days) I now have this which does fill my gaps and works great for one month.  As soon as I ask for two months worth by changing month(obsDate) IN (6) to month(obsDate) IN (6,7) it skips days if they happen to clash in month 6 and 7.  Grrrrrr, am so close!

```
        SELECT CAST(obsDate AS DATE) as obsDate, 
            (CASE 
                WHEN COUNT(id) > 12 THEN COUNT(id) 
                ELSE 0 
              END) numOfHoursAtHigh 
        FROM diseaseScores
        WHERE diseaseID=2 
           AND siteID=72160 
           AND numOfRotationYears=3 
           AND currentScore > 16 
           AND month(obsDate) IN (6) 
          GROUP BY CAST(obsDate AS DATE) 
        UNION
        SELECT CAST(obsDate AS DATE) AS obsDate, 
            0 AS numOfHoursAtHigh 
        FROM diseaseScores
        WHERE diseaseID=2 
           AND siteID=72160 
           AND numOfRotationYears=3 
           AND currentScore <= 17       
           AND month(obsDate) IN (6)
           and day(obsDate) NOT IN      --<-- added from here
           (
        SELECT distinct day(obsDate) 
        FROM diseaseScores
        WHERE diseaseID=2 
           AND siteID=72160 
           AND numOfRotationYears=3 
           AND currentScore > 16 
           AND month(obsDate) IN (6) 
           )                           --<-- to here to omit the duplicates
        GROUP BY CAST(obsDate AS DATE)
        ORDER BY CAST(obsDate AS DATE)
```

To answer to the question around the expected result.  Its one record for each day of the month (or months) giving to columns.  A date and then an integer for numOfHoursAtHigh e.g

```
        2016-06-01  0
        2016-06-02  0
        2016-06-03  0
        2016-06-04  0
        2016-06-05  23
        2016-06-06  23
        2016-06-07  23
        2016-06-08  23
        2016-06-09  23
        2016-06-10  0
        2016-06-11  0
        2016-06-12  0
        2016-06-13  0
        2016-06-14  0
        2016-06-15  0
        2016-06-16  0
        2016-06-17  13
        2016-06-18  23
        2016-06-19  0
        2016-06-20  14
        2016-06-21  23
        2016-06-22  16
        2016-06-23  0
        2016-06-24  0
        2016-06-25  0
        2016-06-26  0
        2016-06-27  0
        2016-06-28  0
        2016-06-29  0
        2016-06-30  0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create another `SELECT` that is the same as the original, modify the part of your `WHERE` clause that is filtering out the results you want (`currentScore > 16`), and then `UNION` them together.

```
SELECT CAST(obsDate AS DATE) as obsDate, 
    (CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(id) > 12 THEN COUNT(id) 
        ELSE 0 
      END) numOfHoursAtHigh 
FROM diseaseScores
WHERE diseaseID=2 
   AND siteID=72160 
   AND numOfRotationYears=3 
   AND currentScore > 16 
   AND month(obsDate) IN (6) 
  GROUP BY CAST(obsDate AS DATE) 
UNION
SELECT CAST(obsDate AS DATE) AS obsDate, 
    0 AS numOfHoursAtHigh 
FROM diseaseScores
WHERE diseaseID=2 
   AND siteID=72160 
   AND numOfRotationYears=3 
   AND currentScore < 17       --<-- note the change
   AND month(obsDate) IN (6) 
GROUP BY CAST(obsDate AS DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(obsDate AS DATE)
```

Comment: Yes very nice I like this.   It does almost work perfect.  For some reason its  showing two records fro 2016-06-17.  one incorrect at 0 and one correct at 13.  Its also doing this for 2016-06-20 and 2016-06-22.  An trying to figure out why ATM

Answer (score 0):

Hi,
 You can have the below query,

```
SELECT  DS.dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, obsDate)) as obsDate,
CASE 
WHEN  DS1.COUNT(id) > 12 THEN COUNT(id)
ELSE 0
END AS numOfHoursAtHigh
  FROM diseaseScores DS
  INNER JOIN (
SELECT dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, obsDate)) AS date, COUNT(id)
FROM diseaseScores GROUP BY  date
) DS1
ON DS.date = DS1.obsDate
AND DS.diseaseID=2 
AND DS.siteID=721DS.60 
AND DS.numOfRotationYears=3 
AND DS.currentScore > 16 
AND DS.month(obsDate) IN (6) 
ORDER BY DS.obsDate;
```